# Second opinion on declined flag for "not an answer"

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, deleted-answers, not-an-answer, specific-answer

So recently went to flag something and found my last flag had been declined. After reviewing it as suggested, the reason for the decline didn't really make sense to me -- maybe the feedback was unintentionally generic or something.

Screenshot of flagged answer below for <10k users, which has been deleted by a moderator since I flagged it (username intentionally omitted):

[image: deleted answer]

The respective question is [What happens if javascript operator "new" fails on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209445/what-happens-if-javascript-operator-new-fails-on-node-js), and the reason for my declined flag is

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

As I said, this seems like generic feedback, given that this deleted answer did not appear to have any relevant information to the question, at least to me.

tl;dr Can someone clarify why this shouldn't have been flagged as "not an answer"?

Comment: I declined the flag. The later half of the post "If your constructors fails with an error, then this error is propagated up the stack and the rest of your task is dropped, especially the task that would have used your created object." still seems like an attempt to answer. We usually downvote bad attempts at answers, rather than delete. (see [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/4099593))

Comment: @BhargavRao thanks for the feedback. It wasn't clear to me that was considered an attempt to answer the question, since the first half seemed an attempt to disregard the question entirely. I had interpreted it as an explanation of why the question shouldn't be answered. In the future, I'll just downvote similar answers instead if I see an attempt to include _any_ technical information whatsoever, since that seems to be the criteria for "an answer".

Comment: In general, try to see if you can salvage the post by an edit. If not _then_ downvote. (Leave a comment if you think that a comment would help).

Comment: @BhargavRao I used to leave comments with feedback, until one user took it upon himself to contact the company I work for and call me an asshole for allegedly downvoting his post. I no longer leave comments in these situations for that reason.

Comment: True, there have been many similar cases. Unfortunately people put a lot of value for some online reputation points, and care enough to act weirdly in real life. I wonder if SE, as a company, can do something to protect its trusted users from these people.

Comment: This is one of those cases where "attempt to answer" just doesn't seem quite enough of a description anymore. At this point, I don't think there is any way to spell it out in words. There's also the fact that there's actually a grey area for this issue - within the grey area, whether an answer is attempting to answer the question can actually be *subjective*.

Comment: @BoltClock obligatory [I know it when I see it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)

Comment: @Patrick Roberts: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a degree of moderator discretion and we all have slightly differing opinions on this particular subject. This can make it hard on flaggers. My advice is: flag in good faith. Use your best judgement. The occasional declined flag is nothing to be concerned about.